# UICollectionView understanding visible cells log

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'd like to know how to understand the results of `[collectionview indexPathsForVisibleItems]`. I'm trying to implement lazy loading and I have a `collectionView` with 3 images across and 2 and a half rows visible when the `viewController` loads. In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` I'm logging like this:

```
NSArray *visible = [collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
NSLog(@"%@", visible);
for (NSIndexPath *index in visible) {
    NSLog(@"%d", index.row);
}
```

The output is:

```
2014-04-22 19:51:35.832 Test App[55175:60b] (
)

2014-04-22 19:51:35.834 Test App[55175:60b] (
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac4f30> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}"
)
2014-04-22 19:51:35.834 Test App[55175:60b] 0

2014-04-22 19:51:35.835 Test App[55175:60b] (
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac4f30> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5030> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}"
)
2014-04-22 19:51:35.835 Test App[55175:60b] 0
2014-04-22 19:51:35.835 Test App[55175:60b] 1

2014-04-22 19:51:35.836 Test App[55175:60b] (
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac50c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac4f30> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5030> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}"
)
2014-04-22 19:51:35.836 Test App[55175:60b] 2
2014-04-22 19:51:35.837 Test App[55175:60b] 0
2014-04-22 19:51:35.837 Test App[55175:60b] 1

2014-04-22 19:51:35.838 Test App[55175:60b] (
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac4f30> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac50c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5030> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5150> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}"
)
2014-04-22 19:51:35.838 Test App[55175:60b] 0
2014-04-22 19:51:35.839 Test App[55175:60b] 2
2014-04-22 19:51:35.839 Test App[55175:60b] 1
2014-04-22 19:51:35.839 Test App[55175:60b] 3
```

And so on. And as I scroll, the values change. How do I make sense of these values? Do they indicate which cells are on the screen? If so, how? Row - cell? I'm confused. I know I will use the `didEndDisplayingCell:` to cancel the `NSOperation`, but which value should I check for?

Comment: You know you don't need to do any of this? UICollectionView works much like UITableView in that it reuses cells that scroll off screen. This saves on memory and is actually very efficient. You don't need to do any of this checking that is in your code.

Comment: I know it reuses it but I still want to use lazy loading so I would need to know which cells to load and which not to.  Instead of just throwing imageWithContentsOfFile or Url into every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5150> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}"`

First number after `path =` is `0` - it's the number of section. Second number is `3` - it's the number of row/cell.

```
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac4f30> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac50c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5030> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xaac5150> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}"
```

The lines above tell us that currently the 4 first rows/cells from the 1st section are visible.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  So I could probably just have an array of visible cells and when the scrollview scrolls, I could check to see if new indexes are in my array?  And if they're not, cancel the operation.  Right logic?

Comment: @denikov, yes, the logic is right. As far as I can tell, of course.